# RegEx ignoring part of string to extract out text

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds

I have the following string:

```
@delimabc@delim@delim123@delim@delim456@delim
```

and I need to write a .Net RegEx that finds 3 matches in this example (but assume the number of matches will be variable:

- abc
- 123
- 456

How can I write a RegEx so that the expression only matches the first and second @delim, and then the third and fourth and so on?

The following will of course capture from the first to the last instance of the @delim string.

```
@delim(.+)+@delim
```

Comment: .net regular expressions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@delim(.+?)@delim
```

Try this .Set `g` flag.Just modifed your regex to add `?`.Grab the caotures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/1

Answer (score 2):

You could use look behind like:

```
(?<=@delim)\w+
```

`(?<=@delim)` is using a  **Positive Lookbehind** which will match the characters `@delim` literally (case sensitive)

while `\w+` will match any word character from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. To include or exclude characters you could replace `\w` by `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and include the new characters or remove those that should not be evaluated in your expression.

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jJ4eF7/2)**

Here is .NET Online Demo:

**[.NET Online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d92Oi1)**

**VB.NET version**

```
Dim sampleInput="@delimabc@delim@delim123@delim@delim456@delim"
Dim results = Regex.Matches(sampleInput,"(?<=@delim)\w+")

For Each item As Group In results
    Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}", item)
Next
```

**C# Version**

```
var sampleInput = "@delimabc@delim@delim123@delim@delim456@delim";
var results = Regex.Matches(sampleInput, "(?<=@delim)\\w+");

foreach (Group item in results) {
    Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}", item);
}
```

**Updated version:**

```
(?<=@delim)[^@].+?(?=@delim|$)
```

Comment: How would you extract the results out to match groups? Nest the paranthesis?

Comment: I see, just by wrapping \w+ with () - @delim(.+?)@delim

Comment: @mservidio I am adding the .net demo

Comment: If I wanted to include any characters at all would it still be valid to use .+ instead of \w+? IE: a @ symbol is something that could be within the string that I want to capture.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you're saying about the character match set.

Comment: There's an issue with using \w+. I need to capture any characters that fall between each start and end boundary string of @ delim. If I replace \w+ with .+ the positive lookbehind logic doesn't work as I expected. How can I use positive lookbehind and capture the entire group string behind the start and ending boundary string '@ delim'?

Comment: @mservidio How about this: `(?<=@delim)[^@].+?(?=@delim|$)` http://regex101.com/r/yT8hS7/3

Comment: Additionally you could also use `(?<=@delim)(?!@delim).+?(?=@delim|$)` [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yT8hS7/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use split on this regex:

```
(?:@delim)+
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uK8pN2/1)

Alternatively replace given regex pattern by **an empty string**.